# How to get correct number formatting of formula result in excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Excel has property to set number formatting automatically for some numbers or formula results. For example, if I enter formula '=12%+12%' it returns 24.00% as a result. But when I use xlsxwriter module to write formula it gives me not formatted value 0.24

I use the next:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=12%+12%')
workbook.close()
```

When I open created file I see 0.24 result in the cell. And to apply autoformatting I need to select cell and press Enter.

So my question is how to write formula and apply excel auto number formatting if it is possible.

Comment: that's nothing to do with the formula itself. that's extra code in excel (the user interface/input stuff) trying to interpret what you want and adding the formatting in parallel. since you're NOT using excel, that extra code doesn't exist, and you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe there is way to automate something like opening created file, executing double click on the cell and pressing Enter on the MacOS to avoid doing it manually?

Comment: People still use Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Excel sets a number format automatically for percent results but it is also possible to do it manually, in Excel, using the `0%` number format.

You can do the same in XlsxWriter using a cell format:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=12%+12%', percent_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works, but it is important for me to get auto detected format from Excel. For example if I write '=12%+(12)%' instead of '=12%+12%' it should be General format and I need to see this.

Comment: "Auto-detection" is something that Excel does at runtime. It isn't available via the file format and thus not available via XlsxWriter. You should be able to simulate it from your program by adding the required number format to the appropriate formula. You can get a `General` format by omitting the number format from the cell.